# FlowDocument Error After I Copied &  Pasted The MSDN Example Code

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, reporting, flowdocument

I am trying to write a reporting module for my application, the application itself is written in `WPF` and after doing some research I have discovered that `FlowDocument`'s are a very flexible format for generating reports. One point the really captured my interest is that someone with `.NET Framework` installed can view a generated `FlowDocument` in their browser.

So I created a document "`Test.xaml`" with the following code:

```
<FlowDocument
  xmlns=’http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation’
  xmlns:x=’http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml’>
  <Paragraph>The quick <Bold>brown fox</Bold> jumps over the lazy dog.
</Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

I then opened the file in `IE9` but received the message "An error occurred in the application..."

Can someone please explain why I am receiving this error?

Comment: Please refrain from 1. Adding tags to your titles, they just clutter things up, we have a tags section for that (which people know how to use). 2. Adding a "thanks"-footer, they are also not desireable as they are considered to be noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the error you are getting, I got it too when I copied and pasted the MSDN example code. The single and double quotes are wrong, if you change them it will work.

```
<FlowDocument
    xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
    xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'>
    <Paragraph>The quick <Bold>brown fox</Bold> jumps over the lazy dog.</Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

Comment: Ha! Thanks for that, it would be great if you could also elaborate on my other questions as well.

Comment: @AlexHopeO'Connor I would if I had used a FlowDocument in the same way you are wanting. I have used them, but as part of a logging framework using a RichTextBox as a Container.

Comment: Changed the question and marked you as the answer due to a lack of progress =/